Sending commands to Alexa via text using API
Since the AVS (Alexa Voice Services) have been abandoned I don't see anymore a reliable way to automate sending command to Alexa.
My use case is building and Android plugin for Tasker/Macrodroid which allows users to trigger Alexa commands via text in order to create cross-system automations.
So far my best bets are:

AVS: allows exactly that but it's no longer available
Send Alexa app an intent: but this does not happen in the background and requires user confirmation

Am I missing anything?
Specifically I see two open questions:

is there a way to register a new app to AVS and still use it?
is there a way to send a background intent to the android Alexa api and have it just execute the command?

e.g.: Tedee smart locks have an Alexa Skill but not a Tasker plugin, I'd like to send the text "Alexa open the door to the office" to an API and have Alexa open the door. This way the user can enter the above text in the plugin and it will execute

What do you mean by "Alexa commands" ?  What are you looking for Alexa to do ?

@allthepies I've added more details to the description with an example
